# New to programing can't figure this out

Tags: python

```
def LangConverter():
lang1 = input("Please select a language ")
if lang1 == "English":
    lang2 = input("what langauge would you like to convert to ") 
    if lang2 == "Spanish":

        
         greeting = input("what would you like to say ")
         if greeting == "hello":
          print("Hola")
         words1 = input("is this your first time speaking spanish ")
         if words1 == ("yes" "Yes" "Yeah"):
                print("Si")
                word4 = input("Say something I will translate it")
         if word4 == ("How are you"):
                print("Que Paso")


    if lang2 == "French":
         fwords = input("what would you like to say")
         if fwords == "Hello":
            print("Bonjour")
```

LangConverter()

The main problem that I'm facing is when I type in french the frenchwords input won't run on terminal

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! please read the guide to [ask]. Be sure to always include the full traceback when asking about errors, or if a program produces undesired output, provide the actual and expected behavior. also read the guide to [formatting](/help/formatting). whitespace matters in python and so it's important to make sure your code is formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong indentation:
The *if statement* is actually inside the

```
if lang1 == "english"
```

This code should work

```
def LangConverter():
lang1 = input("Please select a language ")
if lang1 == "English":
    lang2 = input("what langauge would you like to convert to ") 
    if lang2 == "Spanish":

        
         greeting = input("what would you like to say ")
         if greeting == "hello":
          print("Hola")
         words1 = input("is this your first time speaking spanish ")
         if words1 == ("yes" "Yes" "Yeah"):
                print("Si")
                word4 = input("Say something I will translate it")
         if word4 == ("How are you"):
                print("Que Paso")


if lang2 == "French":
    fwords = input("what would you like to say")
    if fwords == "Hello":
       print("Bonjour")
```

Comment: That, just as the original code, is not propely indented, making it useless for Python!

Comment: Dude it worked thank you!! I thought the If Lang2 == "French" would have to be aligned to If lang2 == Spanish since it was either that or this. Thank you bro. Also do you have any good resources to learn python? or guidance I suppose lool

Comment: @Squash101 Generally a good way to start is to go through a Python crash course, learn about the very basics, then pick up a project or two and try to make it work